Is there a way to add unique information to a 'count' metric in Datadog?
Short Question:
Is there a way to add extra unique information to a datadog metric submission? I cannot use tags for this specific information because it will be unique to each submission and therefore too financially costly to use tags.
It would be information associated with the metric, but I would not need to categorize it. Simply, if I selected a metric, I was hoping I could also see a stack track associated with the individual metrics in the “Metric Summary” screen. Or, if we could associate a unique ID with the metric, then we can use that ID to find the stack trace on our applications servers.
Long Question:
I am trying to track error trends in datadog while also providing a way to deep dive into errors. Our application has a global error handler, and there I can add some code to submit a count metric to datadog whenever an unexpected error occurs. Additionally, I would add some metadata to the submission in the form of tags, thereby altogether giving me the ability to count the number of unexpected errors that occur and to categorize them to find patterns.
For example, if an error 252 ”Embedded Java Error” happens in our application, I would submit the following “count” metric to datadog:
metric name: error.count
tags:
{
       “customer_code”:{unique customer code. aka which application received the error}
       “program_name”: …
       “user_name”:….
       “application_version”:2024.01
       “error_code”: 252
       “error_message”:”Embedded Java Error”
}

My problem is, in our programming language any exceptions thrown by external Java libraries return a generic error code and message of: 252 “Embedded Java Error”. It doesn’t matter if the cause was from a NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException, etc, the same generic exception will be thrown.
So, to be able to deep dive into the errors that are reported to datadog, it would be really nice if we could attach a stack trace or unique reference ID to the metric. With a stack track obviously we could see the call stack and figure out what happened. With the reference ID, we could locate the stack trace that is stored on our application servers.

Including a reference id would result in as many unique tag values as just including the original stack trace. The issue is that custom metrics are never going to be a great solution for the problem of investigation application errors. Application Performance Monitoring (APM) is the tool designed to collect information about error stack traces, show relationships between services, and automatically collects metrics about error rates, latency, and request counts.
